# Getting a total value for entities in one column in Excel

Tags: excel, matching

I have an Excel sheet with several columns.  It includes a "Contribution" value for each "Name".

```
Name    Account Contribution
Melkiyah    @admiralm1      250
Adinoe      @adonas1        744319
Adino       @adonas1        203431
Isha        @aevalia        0
Karu        @Afmec          102069
Xar'Rynn    @agent13ozrealx 8915424
Ozreal      @agent13ozrealx 23700016
Xan' Dara   @agent13ozrealx 5558739
Elle Dax    @agent13ozrealx 3400634
Zaffira     @agent13ozrealx 1180483
```

My objective is to create another column that will total all the "Contributions" per "Account", e.g. Adinoe and Adino would be added for an @adonas1 account value.

The end result would show this:

```
Name          Account       Contribution    Total
Melkiyah    @admiralm1      250             250
Adinoe      @adonas1        744319          947750
Adino       @adonas1        203431          947750
Isha        @aevalia        0               0
Karu        @Afmec          102069          102069
Xar'Rynn    @agent13ozrealx 8915424         42755296
Ozreal      @agent13ozrealx 23700016        42755296
Xan' Dara   @agent13ozrealx 5558739         42755296
Elle Dax    @agent13ozrealx 3400634         42755296
Zaffira     @agent13ozrealx 1180483         42755296
```

Comment: Search for *[excel] unique list* then search for *sumif*.

Comment: How about showing an example of what you want for output, what you have tried, and where you have run into problems.  Perhaps a simple pivot table would provide the report you want.

Comment: Edited to show objective better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SUMIF()

Put this in D2 and copy down.

```
=SUMIF(B:B,B2,C:C)
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's the same thing I have in mind.  The full table is a couple hundred records so the idea is to have a formula for the AccountContribution column that will go through all the Account values and add them where appropriate.

Comment: Then just replace `@adonas1` with a cell reference.  See edit. @victorSheckels

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you!